# InstallSchema.php fails to execute

Tags: magento2, database, setup

I've read various posts here but none of them have been helpful.

Steps I have taken:

- Remove `My_Module` from `setup_module` in DB
- Add `Setup/InstallSchema.php`
- Clear `generated/*` directory
- Clear cache
- Execute `magento setup:upgrade`
- I've also tried throwing an exception within the install method. No exception is ever thrown.

```
<?php

namespace My\Module\AttributeMapper\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use My\Module\AttributeMapper\Helper\Product\AttributeData;

/**
 * Upgrade the Catalog module DB scheme
 */
class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     */
    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        $this->addCatalogEav($setup);

        $setup->endSetup();
    }

    /**
     * @param SchemaSetupInterface $installer
     * @return void
     */
    private function addCatalogEav(SchemaSetupInterface $installer)
    {
        $catalogEavTable = $installer->getTable('catalog_eav_attribute');
        $installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
            $catalogEavTable,
            AttributeData::PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTE_OPTION_API_ATTRIBUTE_ID,
            [
                'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                'comment' => 'API Attribute GUID Mapping for Product Attribute'
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Not an actual answer but which version of M2 are you using? If you're using M2.3+ then Schema install scripts are deprecated and you should likely be doing it via the newer Declarative Schema XML https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/declarative-schema/

Comment: check the log files

Comment: @MohitRane - nothing is logged when this is executed :/.

Comment: @rhys-sproutdesk I am on 2.2

Comment: try to add `addCatalogEav()` code to `install()`

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the following schema

```
<?php
namespace My\Module\AttributeMapper\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use My\Module\AttributeMapper\Helper\Product\AttributeData;

/**
 * Upgrade the Catalog module DB scheme
 */
class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     */
    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();
        $connection = $setup->getConnection();
        $connection->addColumn(
            $setup->getTable('catalog_eav_attribute'),
            'name of column',
            [
                'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                'length' => 255,
                'nullable' => true,
                'default' => '',
                'comment' => 'Column Name'
            ]
        );  

    $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

I hope it will help you.